# Why is electric dipole moment represented by "p"?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, dipole, dipole-moment

I recently came across a text where the electric dipole moment was represented as "**d**" instead of the more commonly used "**p**". The reason behind using "**d**" here is probably that "*d*ipole moment" begins with a "d". However, it also made me wonder why the most commonly used symbol of electric dipole moment is "**p**" and not "**d**". What is the reason behind using "**p**" to represent electric dipole moment?

Also, is there any historical reason for this?

Comment: Maybe $p$ for “pole”? I have no idea why charge is $q$ either.

Comment: You should ask your question at the history of science and math SE - https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "p" as in Polarisation.

Comment: p as in pollos hermanos

Comment: @Avantgarde thanks for letting me know about the history of science and math SE. I will ask this there too.

Comment: @frapadingue thank you very much for your comment. Although I will post this question again in history of math and science SE, I wanted to ask the following here too (because I thought maybe you could share your opinion on it): Historically, what was studied first - electric polarization in materials or the concept of electric dipole moment? If the concept of electric dipole moment was studied first, then, was the representation of this vector quantity changed later when polarization was discovered?

Comment: @G.Smith. I too have no idea why charge is _q_.